# Rewrite URL with ?-sign

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In .htaccess i want to rewrite the URL so...

```
http://example.com/folder/file.php?folder/images/image0001.jpg
```

Becomes...

```
http://example.com/folder/images/image0001.jpg
```

I have been trying...

```
RewriteRule ^folder/file.php?(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But ends up with a unwanted ?-sign...

```
http://example.com/?folder/images/image0001.jpg
```

How do i get rid og the ?-sign ?

Comment: Escape the "?" with "\". ...file.php\?(.*)$

Comment: Dont' work with "\". Then it doesn't rewrite the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't match against the `?` in a rewrite rule, you need to match against either in a `%{QUERY_STRING}` or in `%{THE_REQUEST}`. If you want to rewrite it to `http://example.com/folder/images/image0001.jpg`, meaning that the file **is actually at `/folder/images/image0001.jpg`, then you want this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule ^folder/file\.php$ http://example.com/%1? [R=301,L]
```

If there isn't anything there, obviously that redirect will just result in a 404 Not Found. If this is supposed to be a way to make the URL look "pretty", then you need to rewrite the URL **back** to the query string:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+folder/file\.php\?([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^folder/file\.php$ http://example.com/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)$ /folder/file.php?folder/$1 [L]
```

Comment: If i use your first suggestion the URL ends up being http://example.com/folder/images/image0001.jpg?folder/images/image0001.jpg which works but i would like to get rid of the ?-sign and everything after it.

Comment: @scootergrisen I left out a `?` in the firs texample